# getDerivedStateFromProps doesn't work as expected

Tags: reactjs

Im refactoring my react application and I replaced componentWillRecieveProps with getDerivedstateFromProps.

Then it gives an error saying `Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`

This is my code

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps = nextProps => {
      const { auth, history } = nextProps;
      redirectIfAuthenticated(auth.isAuthenticated, history, './dashboard');

      if (nextProps.errors) {
         this.setState({ 
            errors: nextProps.errors 
         });
      }
   }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

[`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) is not just a rename of `componentWillReceiveProps`, but has a different purpose and syntax. It doesn't have access to the class instance since it is static

Also `getDerivedStateFromProps` is supposed to only update state and not have any side-effects. All side-effects must go in componentDidUpdate

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {

  if (props.errors !== state.prevErrors) {
    return { 
        errors: props.errors,
        prevErrors: props.errors
     }
  }
  return { prevErrors: props.errors}
}

render() {
    const { auth, history } = props;
    if(this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
        return <Redirect to={'/dashboard'} />
    };
    // extra logic here
}
```

Comment: Yes, as long as you are using react-router and using Redirect from it and not `history.push` otherwise do it in componentDidUpdate

Comment: if my redirection part is like this,

    const isAuth = this.props.auth.isAuthenticated;
    if (isAuth) {
      this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
    }

what should I do?

Comment: Are you using react-router?

Comment: Yes. react-router-dom

Comment: Sure then you can simply use `Redirect` instead of history.push in render as I showed in my answer